# Database with admission and Discharge dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to query a database of patient information at a hospital. It contains their admission date, discharge date, unique identifier and the ward they are on.

Here is some sample data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    Identifier INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    admission_Dt DATE NOT NULL,
    DC_dt DATE NOT NULL,
    Ward DATE NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (1, '1/01/2016', '6/01/2016', 'Med 1'); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (2, '3/01/2016', '4/01/2016', 'Med 1'); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (3, '4/01/2016', '7/01/2016', 'Sur 1'); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (4, '2/01/2016', '5/01/2016', 'Sur 1'); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (5, '2/01/2016', '3/01/2016', 'Med 1'); 

INSERT INTO mytable(Identifier, admission_Dt, DC_dt, Ward) 
VALUES (6, '5/01/2016', '6/01/2016', 'Sur 1');
```

I want my query to return results for every day in a range and count of how many patients are on a ward each day. They are defined as being on the ward by the day being between the admission date and discharge date.

The results should look like this

```
+------------+-------+---------------+--+ 
| Date       |  Ward | Patient count |  | 
+------------+-------+---------------+--+ 
| 1/01/2016  | Med 1 |             1 |  | 
| 2/01/2016  | Med 1 |             2 |  |
| 2/01/2016  | Sur 1 |             1 |  | 
| 3/01/2016  | Med 1 |             2 |  | 
| 3/01/2016  | Sur 1 |             1 |  |
| 4/01/2016  | Med 1 |             1 |  | 
| 4/01/2016  | Sur 1 |             2 |  |
| 5/01/2016  | Med 1 |             1 |  | 
| 5/01/2016  | Sur 1 |             2 |  | 
+------------+-------+---------------+--+
```

I can get the query to return the values for a single date with the following query. But I have to define the date in the query.

```
select count(identifier), Ward
from my_table
where admission_Dt > 20160102 and DC_dt< 20160103
group by Ward
```

Returns this result

```
+-------+---------------+--+
| Ward  | Patient_count |  |
+-------+---------------+--+
| Med 1 |             2 |  |
| Sur 1 |             1 |  |
+-------+---------------+--+
```

But what I am really after is to run this for a date range and the output is a list of every date, with a count of patients for each day.

Comment: build a date table and do a JOIN on Date BETWEEN admission_dt and dc_dt.  There are tons of ways of building a date table on the fly if you have a lower and upper range that you are wanting.  If you tag your specific rdbms (mysql, sql-server,oracle) etc. people will be able to help you better.

Comment: You need to know the number of patients you're starting with.  Counting admissions and discharges will only tell you the change in the number of patients on the ward.

Answer (score -1):

What you really want is to put the date filter in your grouping clause. I'm curious as to what dates you have that are GT Jan02 and LT Jan03? Seems like that result set should be empty.